# Wordpress doesn't use domain on anything apart from the home page

Tags: domains, wordpress

I have WordPress installed on a GoDaddy deluxe account. I'm using this account to host multiple sites and just map the domains to the folder: i.e. www.mysite.com/awesome would be www.awesomesite.com. This is transparent to the user.

When I setup wordpress I installed it to a folder www.mysite.com/wordpress. I have a domain www.thesite.com mapped to www.mysite.com/wordpress. When I go to www.thesite.com it looks perfect. As soon as I click on a link it switches the domain to www.msite.com/wordpress. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Instead of just down voting tell me the problem.. leave a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Wordpress Admin site > Setting tab which is under the tools and update all the links there. Change it  from

```
www.mysite.com/wordpress 

to

www.thesite.com
```

Comment: Did that, but now when clicking on a link it gives me a 404 not found the URL it's trying to find is: 
www.thesite.com/wordpress

Comment: It might now work here but try to access it from www.thesite.com . It should work there. And obviously change it correctly. You may need to include Http://www.thesite.com

Comment: Yes, it actually was working, the problem was with the Home link in the menu trying to go to /wordpress instead of just /